# Error: The Entity 'AccountContactRelation' is not found. Contact the vendor for more details

Tags: unlocked-package, versioning, accountcontactrelation

Running into the following error when trying to create a package that has a dependency on a "parent" package:

> The Entity 'AccountContactRelation' is not found. Contact the vendor
> for more details.

Command run:

> sfdx force:package:version:create -p sf-common -d force-app -k
> passwordHere --wait 10 -v DevHub

The package we are currently versioning is a mix of custom objects, with fields, validations rules, and workflow rules. The package that this common package has dependency too has only standard objects such as the Account, Case, and Opportunity. The AccountContactRelation is also added in there.

We've added the "ContactsToMultipleAccounts" feature to our project-scratch-def.json file.

This is how our sfdx-project.json file looks like:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
        "path": "sf-base",
        "default": false,
        "package": "Base",
        "versionName": "ver 1.0",
        "versionNumber": "1.0.35.NEXT"
    },
    {
        "path": "force-app",
        "package": "sf-common",
        "versionName": "ver 0.1",
        "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
        "default": true, 
        "dependencies": [
            {
                "package": "Base",
                "versionNumber": "1.0.0.LATEST"
            }
        ]
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "50.0",
  "packageAliases": {
      "sf-common": "0Ho3Z0000008OKVSB3",
      "Base": "0Ho3Z000000fxTdSIA"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to version specifying the path to the project definition file.

For example:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p sf-test --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json -d force-app -k Password12345 --wait 10 -v DevHub
```